# How to solve this contour integral?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I was reading [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.09168) where I encountered the following contour integral as given in equation (2.4) of the same.

$$S = -i\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} d\omega \log(\omega^2 + m^2 + E)$$

where $m,E \in \mathbb{R}$. When $m^2 \to -E$, the poles $\omega = \pm i \sqrt{m^2 + E}$ pinch the contour (which in our case is the real line). The claim is that this leads to the appearance of singular terms as given in equation (2.5) and consequently $S$ has the following form.

$$S = \sqrt{m^2 + E}.$$

How do I see this?

Comment: Note that that's just the first term in the series for $S$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you mean in the linked paper (I considered only one term from 2.4), or should there be more terms? As for the latter, how do you see this?

Comment: That integral is definitely divergent. For large $\omega$ the integrand is effectively $\log(\omega^2) = 2\log(\omega)$ and $\log(\omega)$ is an increasing function.